# Check what a user or group has access to?

Tags: permissions, 2003

I have a sharepoint 2003 server.  Some permissions are just a mess - very little planning was done so there are lots of permissions set at the site, library, folder and item levels.

I've seen the tool Sharepoint Access Checker, but from the looks of it it doesn't look at folder and item level permissions in the libraries.

Are there any tools that will help me audit permissions in sharepoint 2003?  Ideally I'd like to be able to put in a group or user to check, and get a list of every item they have specific permissions to.  Failing that, something that could just dump all the permissions set at any level into a file I can search through would work.

Comment: 2003 SharePoint server, 2013 is here now... I will highly recommend you upgrade to 2010 or 2013 now! :)

Comment: @arsalan that's what I am working on now.  Hence the need to know what permissions are set now to help planning the migration.